# MockMvc. how to involve a custom object in junit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mocking, spring-test

I need the JUnit test to check the controller. The method of the controller is called by submit a form. This method receives a filled object `EmailDispatchForm form`.

**Here is a snippet from controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/sendEmail"}, method=POST)
public String sendEmail(EmailDispatchForm form,Model model ){
    String status = "OK";

    try {
        workFlows.sendEmailAndRecordHistory(form);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        status = "ERROR";
        model.addAttribute("errDescription", e.getCause().getMessage());
        logger.error(e, e);
    } finally {
        model.addAttribute("sentEmailStatus", status);
    }

    return CommonConstants.VIEW_EMAIL_SENT;
}
```

**This is my junit test:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebConfig.class})
public class HomeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testShowEmailForm() throws Exception{
        mockMvc.perform(get("/emailForm")).andExpect(view().name(CommonConstants.VIEW_EMAIL));
    }
}
```

How you can see, in the controller there is the method `sendEmail()`, which has two parameter: `EmailDispatchForm form`, `Model model`. I have no idea how can I involve this both parameters in junit test to utilize it as i.e. Mock-Objects.

I would be very thankful for assistance and would like to know about some resources (books) to study the subject of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you are trying to use GET and acces a POST URL. 
Your test method should look like this:

```
  @Test
    public void testShowEmailForm() throws Exception{
        mockMvc.perform(post("/sendEmail")).andExpect(view().name(CommonConstants.VIEW_EMAIL));
    }
```

Also add `@RequestBody` in your controller method

```
public String sendEmail(@RequestBody EmailDispatchForm form,Model model )
```

To add the form simply add to the test method:

```
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(json)
```

Where JSON is the JSON form of the `EmailDispatchForm  form` object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

so, i found the other solution. It looks like this:

```js
 @Test
 public void loginUser() throws Exception {
  LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
  loginForm.setPassword("admin");
  loginForm.setUserId("admin");
  
  RequestBuilder request = post("/authentication")
    .flashAttr("loginForm", loginForm);
  
  mockMvc
  .perform(request)
  .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
  .andExpect(redirectedUrl("emailForm"));
 }
```

for the method of controller

```js
 @RequestMapping(value={"/authentication"}, method=POST)
 public String toAuthentication(@ModelAttribute("loginForm")LoginForm loginForm, Model model){
  String view ="redirect:emailForm";
  // some activity here to take the loginForm and process it
  return view;
 }
```